# How to write overloading functions in java

Tags: java, overloading

I wonder what is missing to get the following overloading functions to work?

e.g.

```
List<?> list = ...;
for (Object element : list)
  Fun(element);

public void Fun(Integer element) { ... }
public void Fun(String element) { ... }
public void Fun(MyClass element) { ... }
```

Comment: `element` is not declared as any of those types. Overloading is a compile time concept.

Comment: So how to get runtime overloading?

Comment: There is no such thing. Go through [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) again.

Comment: @user1589188 What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Kon I want the above code compile and based on different lists, the corresponding Fun will be run using that generic for loop, thank you.

Comment: Then you need to add an overloaded Fun method which accepts an Object as a parameter.

Comment: @Kon sorry that was not my intend. I dont process Object, instead I process Integer/String/MyClass. So instead of writing a for loop for Integer/String/MyClass, I want to write just one for loop using Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java uses [double-dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151524/double-dispatch-in-java-example) -- the compiler chooses among overloaded methods based on parameter types, and later, at runtime, the JVM chooses among implementations (overridings) of a method based on the runtime type of `this`.

You're supplying multiple overloadings, but Java will not automatically switch between them.  It looks for an overloading that can accept `(Object element)` and finds none so the compiler rejects your program.

One way to fix this is to have a runtime dispatch method:

```
public void Fun(Object element) {
  if (element instanceof Integer) { Fun((Integer) element); }
  ...
}
```

This works because its static type is very general, and it calls `Fun` with a parameter type whose type is more specific so is dispatched to a different overloading.

Frequent use of `instanceof` is often considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: Yes thank you, I see where this is going. I was just hoping those instanceof can be done implicitly by jvm at runtime based on the actual instance of the Object element, instead of doing it explicitly using that dispatch method.

Answer (score 2):

`Fun(x)` where `x` is of type `Object` will try to find a function with the signature `Fun(Object)`, and you've never declared one. I think you want something like this instead.

```
public void fun(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer)
        ((Integer) obj).someMethod(); // line 3
    else if (obj instanceof String)
        ...
}
```

**Note** cast in line 3. I would also recommend you to follow Java naming conventions: `someMethodName` for functions, and `SomeClassName` for classes.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I fully understand this can be done. Actually thats my original code. I was only thinking if those instanceof can be removed because obviously jvm knows the actual instance of Object obj and would be nice to call appropriate overloading functions for me automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Add the logic in for identifying the type of object and typecast it. Then the code will work as you expected.

```
List<?> list = ...;
for (Object element : list)
// Type cast element to one of the type (Integer, String or MyClass) using Instance of  
  Fun(element);

public void Fun(Integer element) { ... }
public void Fun(String element) { ... }
public void Fun(MyClass element) { ... }
```

Comment: Yes sure. I came from that code and was hoping to simplify it further.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like that

```
public void SuperFun(Object o){
     if(o instanceof Integer)
          Fun((Integer)o);
     if(o instanceof String)
          Fun((String)o);
     if(o instanceof MyClass)
          Fun((MyClass)o);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9) says the following about overloading

> When a method is invoked (§15.12), the number of actual arguments (and
>   any explicit type arguments) and **the compile-time types of the
>   arguments are used, at compile time, to determine the signature of the
>   method that will be invoked (§15.12.2).**

The reference you are trying to use as a method argument is declared as type `Object`, but you don't have an overloaded method that accepts an `Object` argument.

You will have to rethink your design.